Read from 1 database to write to another database in Postgres dbt
I am working with dbt and postgres and I want to take tables from 1 database in postgres, do some querying and create a new table into another postgres database. If that is possible, how would you accomplish that? Would it have to be coded into the profiles.yml file in dbt?

You could create a foreign table, the standard way to interact between different databases (on different servers) within PostgreSQL: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createforeigntable.html

With PostgreSQL, the cleanest approach might involve external data movement tools or scripting due to the database isolation nature of PostgreSQL. However, if you're comfortable with PostgreSQL's advanced features like FDWs, this could be an integrated solution within your database environment. Adjusting dbt to handle this involves mainly configuration and potential scripting rather than straightforward dbt model management due to the limitations in PostgreSQL's cross-database querying capabilities.
